Enabling Live metrics in application insights for Nodejs container app
I have used this GitHub repo (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-node.js.git) which is given in the application Enable Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry for .NET, Node.js, Python, and Java applications (Microsoft azure documentation).
So how to enable live metrics for this?
If I use this, I am able to visualize Application map (with request/failures). But I am not able to get live metrics.
So how to enable live metrics for this application using OpenTelemetry?

Configure the exporter to send telemetry data to Application Insights in a format that supports live metrics. Use the AzureMonitorTraceExporter instead of OTLPTraceExporter. The AzureMonitorTraceExporter is specifically designed to send telemetry data to Azure Monitor.

Yes, Thanks @SureshChikkam I was able to solve the issue.

If my solution is really helpful for you, please accept the solution to my efforts and for the community benefit.


If I use this, I am able to visualize Application map (with request/failures). But I am not able to get live metrics. So how to enable live metrics for this application using OpenTelemetry?

Update the OTLP Exporter use the AzureMonitorTraceExporter instead of OTLPTraceExporter. The AzureMonitorTraceExporter is designed to send telemetry data to Azure Monitor.

Add metrics instrumentation to collect metrics data, such as CPU, memory, and other performance metrics.

azureMonitor.ts:
import { useAzureMonitor, AzureMonitorOpenTelemetryOptions, AzureMonitorTraceExporter } from "@azure/monitor-opentelemetry";
import { trace, metrics, Span, SpanKind, TraceFlags } from '@opentelemetry/api';
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";
import { Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources";
import { SEMATTRS_ENDUSER_ID, SEMATTRS_HTTP_CLIENT_IP, SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID, SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_NAME, SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE, SemanticAttributes, SemanticResourceAttributes } from "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions";
import { BatchSpanProcessor, ReadableSpan, SpanProcessor } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";
import { HttpInstrumentationConfig } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http";
import { NodeMetricExporter } from "@opentelemetry/exporter-node-metrics";

export function initializeTelemetry() {
    const customResource = new Resource({
        [SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_NAME]: "my-helloworld-service",
        [SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE]: "my-namespace",
        [SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID]: "my-instance"
    });

    const options: AzureMonitorOpenTelemetryOptions = {
        resource: customResource,
        instrumentationOptions: {
            azureSdk: { enabled: true },
            mongoDb: { enabled: true },
            mySql: { enabled: true },
            postgreSql: { enabled: true },
            redis: { enabled: true },
            redis4: { enabled: true },
        },
    };

    addSpanProcessor(options);
    addOTLPExporter(options);
    useAzureMonitor(options);
    addMetricsInstrumentation();
}

function addMetricsInstrumentation() {
    const exporter = new NodeMetricExporter();
    metrics.addMetricProcessor(exporter);
}

function addSpanProcessor(options: AzureMonitorOpenTelemetryOptions) {
    class SpanEnrichingProcessor implements SpanProcessor {
        forceFlush(): Promise<void> {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        shutdown(): Promise<void> {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        onStart(_span: Span): void {}
        onEnd(span: ReadableSpan) {
            if (span.kind == SpanKind.INTERNAL) {
                span.spanContext().traceFlags = TraceFlags.NONE;
            } else {
                span.attributes["CustomDimension1"] = "value1";
                span.attributes["CustomDimension2"] = "value2";
                span.attributes[SEMATTRS_HTTP_CLIENT_IP] = "<IP Address>";
                span.attributes[SEMATTRS_ENDUSER_ID] = "<User ID>";
            }
        }
    }

    if (options.spanProcessors?.length > 0) {
        options.spanProcessors.push(new SpanEnrichingProcessor());
    } else {
        options.spanProcessors = [new SpanEnrichingProcessor()];
    }
}

function addOTLPExporter(options: AzureMonitorOpenTelemetryOptions) {
    const traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter();
    if (options.spanProcessors?.length > 0) {
        options.spanProcessors.push(new BatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter));
    } else {
        options.spanProcessors = [new BatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter)];
    }
}


Added metrics instrumentation using NodeMetricExporter to collect metrics data. Updated the resource creation to use new Resource() constructor.


